# Removing the object Name field when viewing all records in a tab

Tags: custom-object

Sorry, this is a very noobie question

I have a custom object with it's own tab. I don't want to see the standard 'Name' field appearing on any layouts since it's an Auto Number, so I removed it from all the page and search layouts.

But when I click my new tab, and click Go next to the View menu dropdown, all I see is a layout (?)  with the Name field in there.

How do I get at it to change it?

Many thanks
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Ah, whoops, just found it.

To fix, you click Edit next to the Go button to create a new View, and share it with everyone.

Seems odd that SF doesn't wrap this up with Page Layouts though...